# why doesn't aws:userid work as per the s3 bucket policy example?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-iam

I'm getting Access Denied for the following policy:

```
{
  "Version": "2012-10-17",
  "Statement": [
    {
      "Sid": "InsideUserBucket",
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Action": [
        "s3:*"
      ],
      "Resource": [
        "arn:aws:s3:::cbd-backup-us-east-1/${aws:userid}", "arn:aws:s3:::cbd-backup-us-east-1/${aws:userid}/*"
      ]
    },
    {
      "Sid": "ListBucketPolicy",
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Action": [
        "s3:ListBucket"
      ],
      "Resource": [
        "arn:aws:s3:::cbd-backup-us-east-1"
      ],
      "Condition": {"StringLike": {"s3:prefix": ["${aws:userid}/*"]}}
    }
  ]
}
```

I'm connecting through the .NET AWSSDK using a successfully connected client "m_client" that is connected using IAM user credentials. The user is in a group, and the group has the above policy on it. I am not using ACLs. I have tried setting no prefix.

```
            ListObjectsRequest listRequest = new ListObjectsRequest();
            listRequest.BucketName = "cbd-backup-us-east-1";
            listRequest.Prefix = "AKIAJ5GQCDM2IBBVJNWA/";

            using (ListObjectsResponse listResponse = m_client.ListObjects(listRequest))
            {
                ...
            }
```

The only way I can get it to work is by manually putting the userid into the policy in place of ${aws:userid}, or wildcarding everything so the user can access any bucket. I have verified my bucket exists and has no policy attached to it.

It seems like aws might not be expanding the ${aws:userid} variable correctly, but I can't figure out a way to debug that. Any ideas?

Comment: Also, I should mention that it works in the simulator but not when I use AWSSDK. I can't tell how to see the arn using the .NET SDK so I can't verify what the difference is. They are two completely different interfaces.

Comment: Update: I realised I was using an older version of AWSSDK, so I tried updating my AWSSDK and fixed my code to match, but I still get the same problem.

Answer (score 0):

Your `listRequest.Prefix` is set to an Access Key (AKIAJ5GQCDM2IBBVJNWA).

However, `{aws:userid}` resolves to a User ID, which would be the friendly name of your IAM user (eg "Ryan").

So, just set `listRequest.Prefix='Ryan/'`.

Comment: As far as I can tell from the sparse documentation, ${aws:userid} should be the user access key, and ${aws:username} is the friendly name eg. Ryan like you mention. So I think I've got that part correct, since I want to user the unique access key?

Comment: You can see this in the table at the bottom of http://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/PolicyVariables.html

Comment: This all actually works if I switch to using ${aws:username} and provide the simple username instead of the large ID, so that further convinces me that aws is bugged when it comes to ${aws:userid}

Comment: @Ryan, ${aws:userid} doesn't refer to the access key, but a separate unique id for the user.  The access key can be cycled, but the unique id is always the same.  http://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/reference_identifiers.html#identifiers-unique-ids

Answer (score 0):

This appears to be a typo in the AWS documentation. When setting up the policy you need to use `aws:userId` (note the capital `I`). So your condition statement should be:

```
"Condition": {"StringLike": {"s3:prefix": ["${aws:userId}/*"]}}
```

Comment: I don't think that's correct. Key names are case-insensitive. For example, aws:CurrentTime is equivalent to AWS:currenttime. (per https://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/reference_policies_variables.html)